# Non blocking input prompt? node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am working on a chat app using socket.io/node.js, in the terminal,I am able to chat with another session, but when I send a message to in order to read the message I have the either hit enter on the prompt, or type a message, not the best. Any alternatives to console.log()?

The console.log containing the nick and message variables, is fired when the new message event is received, any alternatives to make it more realtime?
I am using the Prompt-Sync module.

EDIT: on message event snippet.

On message function:

```
        socket.on('msg',function(data){ 

         var newmessage = data.m;
         var newmsgnick = data.nick;
         newmessagefunc(newmessage,newmsgnick)

        });
```

newmessagefunc function:

```
        function newmessagefunc(message,nick){
         console.log(nick+": "+message);
         message = i("message: ")
            }
```

The message log:

```
 message: Hello - how goes?
 Ozzie: Hello - how goes?
 message: Hello - ?
 Ozzie: it goes well. 
 message:
```

To read the message the other user sent, I have to either submit a message, or just enter on the message prompt, they do not show as they are sent, as socket.io is said to be able to do, any ways around this?

Comment: You will need to show a minimal example of your code, but if you have an onmessage callback you should be updating your chat screen in there.

Comment: I will add the onmessege event snippet.

Comment: What is the `i` function doing?

Comment: its for the readline prompt, its a input prompt.

Comment: If you mean the [native prompt dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), that is a blocking dialog the rest of the script is paused while it is open. I can provide an example of using a textbox and button to send messages so you do not need to use prompt if that is the case

Comment: Ahhh, that would make sense, could you send the example? thank you!

Comment: Any examples of none blocking terminal based input prompt modules?

Comment: are you mean server-side terminal prompt? If so, how it should go, if you run several async prompts at one time?

Comment: This is client side.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a message when there is an incoming message. This is forcing you to type a message before you display the incoming message.

```
socket.on('msg',function(data){ 
  var newmessage = data.nm;
  var newmsgnick = data.nn;
  console.log(newmessage);
});
```

Now, this will print the incoming message. Keep the prompt code outside of this block.

```
while(typeof message === "undefined"){
  message = i("message: ") 
}
socket.emit('msg', {'nm':message, 'nn':'nick'});
```